# $A:H \to H$, $Ax = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n} \langle x, e_{n} \rangle f_{n}$, $s_{n} \searrow 0$, $e_{n}$, $f_{n}$ orthonormal bases of H

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with two orthonormal bases $e_{n}$ and $f_{n}$, and let $s_{n}>0$ be a strictly decreasing sequence s.t. $s_{n} \to 0$. Let $A: H \to H$ be an operator defined by $Ax = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n} \langle x, e_{n} \rangle f_{n}$.

I wish to prove several properties of this operator:

1) $A$ is well-defined, bounded and compact, and $A^{*}x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n} \langle x, f_{n} \rangle e_{n},$ where $A^{*}$ is the adjoint operator.

2) If the property $||A^{*}x|| \leq ||Ax||$ holds for all $x \in H$, then $e_{n} = f_{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I was able to prove 1) fairly easily. The only part that required a little bit of effort was compactness, where I used the fact that $A$ is compact iff $$x_{n} \rightharpoonup 0 \implies Ax_{n} \to 0.$$

The arrow on the left denoted weak convergence, and the arrow on the right strong convergence.

However, I can only prove 2) partially. Here's what I have. We have $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle \leq \langle A^{*}x, A^{*}x \rangle$, i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s_{n}^{2} | \langle x, f_{n} \rangle |^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n}^2 |\langle x, e_{n} \rangle |^2,$$ i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_{n}^2(|\langle x, f_{n}\rangle |^2 - |\langle x,e_{n} \rangle|^2) \leq 0,$$ i.e. $$|\langle x, f_{n} \rangle| = |\langle x, e_{n} \rangle|$$ for all $n$.

By plugging in $x=f_{m}$, I get $f_{m} \bot e_{n}$ for all $m \neq n$ and $|\langle f_{m}, e_{m} \rangle| = 1$, i.e. $f_{m} = e^{i\theta_{m}} e_{m}$ for all $m$, where $e^{i\theta_{m}} = \langle f_{m}, e_{m} \rangle$.

Furthermore, $||f_{n} - e_{n}||^{2} = 2(1-\text{Re}\langle f_{n}, e_{n} \rangle)$, so if I prove that $\langle f_{n}, e_{n} \rangle = 1$, I'm done. However, I can't seem to prove this.

Does anybody know a neat trick or a hint that could solve this?

Comment: Are you sure $(2)$ is true? If $f_n  = -e_n$ then $A^* = A$ so $\|A^*x\| = \|Ax\|$. Also, how did you conclude that $\|A^*x\| \le \|Ax\| \implies \|A^{**}x\| \le \|A^*x\|$?

Comment: Ohhh, that's true. Just because the property holds for $A$, doesn't mean it holds for $A^{*}$. But I think the equalities $|\langle x, f_{n} \rangle| = |\langle x, e_{n} \rangle|$ still hold. Let me make the edit.

Comment: In fact, for any unimodular sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ if we define $f_n = \lambda_ne_n$ it is again an orthonormal basis and we have $Ax = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n\lambda_n\langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$ and $A^*x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n\overline{\lambda_n}\langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$ both having the norm $$\|Ax\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n^2\left|\langle x ,e_n\rangle\right|^2 = \|A^*x\|^2$$

Comment: It's an exercise in a problem set that I got, so it's not impossible that there's a mistake. I think the point of the exercise is to show that, for this class of operators, normal implies self-adjoint (and even a little bit more than that, since, as you pointed out, this condition is not equivalent to $A$ being normal). However, again, it's possible that there's a mistake... Your counterexample makes total sense.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I guess what I got was as far as one could get in the exercise. I probably should've seen the mistake myself, considering the result I got.